# How to Add php variable in laravel function

Tags: php, sql, laravel, syntax-error, laravel-5

```
$username='Vasim';

$results = DB::select(
    'Select r.LocationId ,LM.Name+'-'+LM.LocationCode as LocationName
        from User_Master u(nolock), UserRoleLoc_link r(nolock)
        left join Location_Master LM(nolock)
        on r.LocationId = LM.LocationId
        Where r.UserId = u.UserId
        AND u.UserName = '$username' AND LM.Status = 1 AND
        (IsNull(NullIf('',''),'1')='1' Or r.LocationId = '') 
        AND LM.isLocationOnline = 1
        Group by r.UserId, u.UserName, 
            r.LocationId,u.Password,LM.Name,LM.LocationCode
        having COUNT(r.UserId) > 0
        Order By Count(r.UserId) DESC');
```

> Error : syntax error, unexpected '$username' (T_VARIABLE)

how can i use my variable in this query

Comment: first thing it should be '.$username.' check concatination

Comment: Use "" instead of '' in your query.

Comment: Always fun when stackoverflow code syntax highlighting makes the problem quite clear!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write your query with Double quote`""` instead of single Quote`''`.

```
$results = DB::select("SELECT r.LocationId ,LM.Name+'-'+LM.LocationCode as LocationName From User_Master u(nolock), UserRoleLoc_link r(nolock) 
    LEFT JOIN Location_Master LM(nolock) on r.LocationId = LM.LocationId 
    WHERE r.UserId = u.UserId AND u.UserName = '$username' 
    AND LM.Status = 1 AND (IsNull(NullIf('',''),'1')='1' Or r.LocationId = '') 
    AND LM.isLocationOnline = 1 GROUP BY r.UserId, u.UserName, r.LocationId,u.Password,LM.Name,LM.LocationCode HAVING COUNT(r.UserId) > 0 
    ORDER BY Count(r.UserId) DESC");
```

PHP executes variable in double quotes not in single quote.

```
$username = 'vasim';
echo '$username';  // $username
echo "$username";  // vasim
```

Hope it will help you :-)

Answer (score 2):

Use your db query like the following string:

```
   $username='Vasim';
   $results = DB::select("Select r.LocationId ,LM.Name+'-'+LM.LocationCode as LocationName from User_Master u(nolock), UserRoleLoc_link r(nolock) left join Location_Master LM(nolock) 
                on r.LocationId = LM.LocationId
                Where r.UserId = u.UserId
                AND u.UserName = '".$username."'  AND LM.Status = 1 AND
                (IsNull(NullIf('',''),'1')='1' Or r.LocationId = '') AND LM.isLocationOnline = 1
                Group by r.UserId, u.UserName, r.LocationId,u.Password,LM.Name,LM.LocationCode
                having COUNT(r.UserId) > 0
                Order By Count(r.UserId) DESC");
```

Please check the double quoted string and concatenation change in the query there.

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S22]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'Vasim'. (SQL: Select r.LocationId ,LM.Name+'-'+LM.LocationCode as LocationName from User_Master u(nolock), UserRoleLoc_link r(nolock) left join Location_Master LM(nolock) 
on r.LocationId = LM.LocationId
Where r.UserId = u.UserId
AND u.UserName = Vasim AND LM.Status = 1 AND
(IsNull(NullIf('',''),'1')='1' Or r.LocationId = '') AND LM.isLocationOnline = 1
Group by r.UserId, u.UserName, r.LocationId,u.Password,LM.Name,LM.LocationCode
having COUNT(r.UserId) > 0
Order By Count(r.UserId) DESC)

Comment: @DeepKakkar: If you write query by concatation way then you should write UserName = '".$username."' instead of current one.